# VB.Net: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS Secure Channel

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I just want to get current system IP from Cloudfare from a console application. I looked a lot of online resources, but I couldn't find any working piece of code with HTTPS protocol.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim client As New System.Net.WebClient
        Dim data As String = client.DownloadString("https://1.1.1.1/cdn-cgi/trace")
        Console.WriteLine(data)
    End Sub

End Module
```

But it doesn't work and throws a very long error. I don't know how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Post the error text, not images of the error. Which .NET version are you using, on which OS? Most likely, the service is using TLS1.2 but the .NET version and/or OS don't support it. If you google for this error message you'll find a *lot* of duplicates from 5 years ago. That's when all major web services started requiring TLS1.2

Comment: The code shown works when I try it using Visual Studio 2017, .NET Framework 4.8, on Windows 10.

Comment: Most likely you're using unsupported Windows *and* .NET versions. The oldest supported Windows version is Windows 10, which uses TLS1.2 automatically. TLS1.2 was added in .NET 4.5 but automatic use was added in 4.6. The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2 but even 4.6.1 goes [out of support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework) in a year.

Comment: I posted the error, but it was not letting me post that, saying "your submission looks like has code only add some description"

Here is the complete stack trace: https://paste.ee/p/Q2ZBx

Comment: I am on Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: So 100% unsupported. Again *post the error as text*. The important parts are truncated. There may be a different error caused by an invalid certificate

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so what should I do to make it work with current OS and VS version? Or it won't work. I added the pastee ink in above comment

Comment: The version of Vislua Studio doesn't specify the version of the .NET Framework. VS 2015 could be used to create .NET 2 applications as well. Which *.NET Framework* version are you targeting? And again, post the actual error. You may be able to patch Windows 8 to work with TLS1.2, but really you should just move to a supported OS and .NET version

Comment: Target framework is set to 4.5.2

Comment: The real solution is to stop using unsupported OS and .NET versions. Use at least 4.6.2. You'll have to upgrade in 1 year anyway. Besides. .NET 4.x versions are binary replacements so your customers and clients probably already run on fresher runtimes.  If search SO for that error message you'll find a lot of duplicates from 5-6 years ago

Comment: There's a lot of documentation and MS articles on how to enable TLS 1.2 too, like [How to enable TLS 1.2 on clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your help. I have Windows 10 ISO, so I will just install that.